# How does one implement Graded Browser Support?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progressive-enhancement

I was just introduced to the concept of [Graded Browser Support](https://github.com/yui/yui3/wiki/Graded-Browser-Support), and the concept as a whole sounds great! Upon a deeper evaluation, however, I am at a bit of a loss as to how to implement it in a reasonable manner.

In particular, I'm referring to [C-grade](https://github.com/yui/yui3/wiki/Graded-Browser-Support#c-grade) support:

> C-grade is the base level of support, providing core content and functionality. It is sometimes called core support. Delivered via nothing more than semantic HTML, the content and experience is highly accessible, unenhanced by decoration or advanced functionality, and forward and backward compatible. Layers of style and behavior are omitted.

So let's say I deem IE 8 and below to be C-grade browsers. How can I deliver only semantic HTML (HTML 5 semantic elements with no added CSS or JS) and still have the website display properly without a JS shim? Is server-side browser sniffing required then?

Comment: C-Grade doesn't mean - "(No CSS or JS)"...I think you've misunderstood the concept.

Comment: @Paulie_D Could you elucidate?

Comment: Sure..first define what you mean by *"still have the website display properly"*

Comment: I'm referring to IE <= 8's inability to properly render HTML 5 semantic elements. If you don't include a JS shim, your website won't display properly on IE <= 8.

Comment: "How can I deliver only semantic HTML (HTML 5 semantic elements with no added CSS or JS) and still have the website display properly without a JS shim?" Unless you deliberately only serve legacy HTML to IE8 and below, you can't. The *reasonable* approach would be to just include the JS shim along with the base styles associated with the shim as a bare minimum.

Comment: If you want the site to look and function exactly the same on IE8 as it looks on modern browsers and not use any Javascript, then don't use HTML5 elements that IE8 doesn't support. It's as simple as that.

Comment: That said, artificially restricting oneself by refusing to use shims just to comply with some design philosophy is a bit too puritan to my tastes.

Comment: @Juhana Okay, that's what I was thinking. So in order to implement bona fide Graded Browser Support, you can't use semantic HTML5 elements? Because IE < 6 probably won't be on your A-grade list and those versions obviously don't support HTML5. Would that be an accurate statement?